# MS Excel Custom Code needed for 10 digit length place filler and symbol use

Tags: excel, formatting, symbols

I would like to make a column uniformed by adding a "~" if the number in the field is not ten digits. For example: 123456789~, 2343456~~~, and 543645~~~~.
Does anyone know how to write this custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom format for the cells like "0*~" would mostly work provided that you could set the column width appropriately. More information [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/number-format-codes-HP005198679.aspx) under the section 'Repeating Characters'

Alternatively, a bit of VBA would do the job.